# average weighted value by region with use of Voronoi in Qgis

Tags: qgis, shapefile, vector, query, voronoi-thiessen

I have a vector layer of Voronoi polygons. This layer has three columns -longitude, latitude, Z-value.
[image]

I need to cut polygons by mask of administrative area and then I need to calculate average-weighted Z-value (AWZ) for every administrative area with use of formula:

```
AWZ = SUM(Z-value*Square_of_polygon_inside_area)/SUM(Square_of_polygon_inside_area)
```

How should I solve this problem?

Answer (score 2):

I am interested in knowing the theory that develops the calculation of the average of weighted elevation by the square of the areas. If you could share it in the comments I would appreciate it.

---

- Make sure that both layers contain singlepart features ([Multipart to singleparts](https://docs.qgis.org/3.4/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#multipart-to-singleparts)) and valid geometries ([Fix geometries](https://docs.qgis.org/3.4/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#fix-geometries)). Also, make sure that both layers are defined in the same CRS ([Reproject Layer](https://docs.qgis.org/3.4/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeneral.html#reproject-layer)).
- Populate a field ([Using Field Calculator](https://docs.qgis.org/3.4/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/attribute_table.html#using-the-field-calculator)) in both attribute tables with the feature's identifier (`$id` expression).
- Perform the union ([Union](https://docs.qgis.org/3.4/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectoroverlay.html#union)) between both layers.
- Select by Value ([Select Features by Value](https://docs.qgis.org/3.4/en/docs/user_manual/introduction/general_tools.html#select-features-by-value)) the resulting features in the *Union* layer that have null value (`is missing` operator) for any of the identification columns, and delete them ([Deleting Selected Features](https://docs.qgis.org/3.4/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/editing_geometry_attributes.html#deleting-selected-features)).
- Calculate the square of the area, for each feature.

  - If you are working with a projected coordinate system, you can calculate the square of the planimetric area with the expression: `(area($geometry))^2`.
  - If you are working with a geographic coordinate system instead (or if you just want to use the ellipsoidal area), you can select the appropriate ellipsoid in the project properties ([General Properties](https://docs.qgis.org/3.4/en/docs/user_manual/introduction/qgis_configuration.html#general-properties)) and calculate the square of the ellipsoidal area of each feature wth the expression: `($area)^2`.
- Calculate the weigthed average for the elevation.

There are some ways to do that. All of them implies to use the `SUM` agreggate function. The simplest way seems to me populate a new field in the *administrative* layer with the following expression:

```
aggregate( 
  'Union', 
  'sum', 
  "area" * "z", 
  "id_2" = attribute( @parent, 'id'))
/
aggregate(
  'Union', 
  'sum', 
  "area",
  "id_2" = attribute( @parent, 'id'))
```

Where `'Union'` is the name of the joined by the `aggregate` function layer (the *Union* layer in this case), `'sum'` is the aggregate to calculate, `"area"` is the name of the field of the squared area calculated in the joined layer, `"z"` is the name of the field of the elevations in the joined layer, and `"id_2" = attribute( @parent, 'id')` is the filter by matching values between the *id_2* field of the joined layer with the value of the *id* field for each feature of the source layer (the *administrative* layer in this case).